# How to handle enums in an indirection with functionpointers at ANSI-C?

Tags: design, c, project-structure

Moinsen,

I am somehow stucked in a design problem. Language is ANSI-C.

Lets assume we have a tinkerbox of software-modules:

- one module for the logic **Logic**
- (at least) one module doing some logging **Logger**
- two modules, both giving a "frame" to let the program run, lets say

  - one with a GUI
  - one for commandline
- ...

Therefore, the same logic could used in a comandline- and a graphic-version of the software. The **Logic** has to log some errors but should not know anything about the specific logger as it could be dependent on the "frame". It is obvious to give **Logic** a function pointer that has to be filled by the frame to bind the used **Logger** to the **Logic**.

At **Logging**-Module (all code Pseudo-ANSI-C):

```
    void Logger_Log(char *sLogText)
    {
      //do some stuff
    }
```

At **Logic**-Module:

```
    void Logic_PseudoLog(char *sLogText)
    {
      printf(sLogText);
    }

    void(* Logic_Log)(char *sLogText) = &Logic_PseudoLog;

    void Logic_SetLogger(void(* LogFct)(char *sLogText))
    {
      Logic_Log = LogFct;
    }
```

At GUI/Cmd-Line:

```
    #include "Logger.h"
    #include "Logic.h"
    Logic_SetLogger(&Logger_Log);
```

Now I want to introduce different severity levels for logging and implement them as an enum in **Logger**:

```
    //Logger.h:
    typedef enum {
      DEBUG,
      INFO,
      ERROR
    } teLogLevel;

    void Logger-Log(char *sLogText, teLogLevel eLevel);
```

And here the problem rises: The function-pointer at Logic needs to have the correct signature. To do so, it has to know about `teLogLevel`. Therefore **Logic** has to know about the **Logger**, exactly the case I wanted to avoid with the indirection in the first place.

```
    #include "Logger.h"
    void(* Logic_Log)(char *sLogText, teLogLevel eLevel);
```

The situation as layed out is just an example. Please don't solve it by saying something like "use `int` instead of `enum`" or "build three functions for the levels". The bottemline question is:

**How to handle enums in an indirection with functionpointers at ANSI-C?**

**How to "inject" enums into a module, that should not now about the origin of the enums?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current design, the **Logic** module already has a dependency on the **Logger** module, but that dependency is hidden. 
The dependency lies in the fact that both **Logic** and **Logger** must agree on the set of functions used for logging (one function) and their signatures (`void (char*)`).

The way out of here is to clearly separate the *interface* from the *implementation*. In particular, the **Logger** module *only* provides the logging interface. The implementations are either provided by the **GUI**/**Cmd-Line** modules, or by separate Logger-Implementation modules that can depend on the GUI/Cmd-Line modules.

The **Logger** module would only consist of a single header file, like this

```
/* File: Logger.h */
typedef enum {
  DEBUG,
  INFO,
  ERROR
} teLogLevel;

typedef void (*LoggerFuncT)(char *sLogText, teLogLevel eLevel);

/* Logger function that discards all logging. Can be used as a safe default. */
static void NullLogFunc(char*, teLogLevel) {}
```

All other modules that either use or implement logging functionality need to refer to this header to know the correct function signatures and other types (including enums).
For example, the **Logic** module would use it like this:

```
#include "Logger.h"
LoggerFuncT Logic_Log = NullPseudoLog;

void Logic_SetLogger(LoggerFuncT LogFct)
{
  Logic_Log = LogFct;
}

void Logic_DoSomething()
{
  Logic_Log("Entering Logic_DoSomething()", DEBUG);
  //...
  Logic_Log("Leaving Logic_DoSomething()", DEBUG);
}
```

In the GUI module, you could have an implementation like this:

```
void GUI_LogToDebugWindow(char* sText, teLogLevel eLevel)
{
    //...
}

/* Let the Logic module use this function as logger.
 * The compiler will complain here if the logger signatures don't match. */
Logic_SetLogger(GUI_LogToDebugWindow);
```

Comment: the typedef puzzles me. Could you give an example how to implement the function using the new type?

Comment: @Oliver: See my update. Unfortunately, the typedef can't be used effectively when defining a function.

Comment: I did it just the way you showed. I hoped, there is a way to use the typedef at the definition of the function I don't see. Something like `LoggerFunct GUI_LogToDebugWindow()`.. But thanks for clarification and the edit. It will hopefully help the next reader!

Answer (score 0):

`Logic.h` declares a function to set the logger function: `Logic_SetLogger()`, in order to use it.

Therefore, `Logic.h` must know the prototype of the logger function, whatever `Logger.h` is, i.e., in the most generic way possible.

This is already the case with the first argument: a pointer to a char.

For the second argument, I see two alternatives:

1. The usual way to handle it is to use an int, which is the generic form of an enum. Representing an error level with an int is very common among C developers.
2. In your case, not wanting an int, you need to use an enum type in the prototype definition of the logger function (which is in `Logic.h` as the argument of `Logic_SetLogger()`). Therefore, `Logic.h` needs to define the enum type as well.

In my opinion, defining error levels in `Logic.h` is not a good design choice.

Comment: Agreed on both points, but 1) is a bit to specific, the logger was more an example, I also have enmus that are "not ordered". 2) I totaly agree at that this is not a good choice. Therefore I asked for a better one..

Comment: In C, enums get ordered as soon as they are defined, even enum Color or enum Fruit. So using an int as a generic form of enum still makes sense.

Comment: I have a different view. Technically you are right, but the strength in enum is, from my point of view, to have speaking names instead of numbers. To stay in the example, I am not only not able to say `Log("Text", DEBUG)` but I also have to know, which int corespondent to DEBUG.